# Load-testing in Orbeon - request generation

Tags: load-testing, orbeon, gatling

I've been trying to use Gatling to load-test our Orbeon servers. More specifically we want to know how many concurrent users the server can handle submitting forms.

I've already captured the requests using Gatling (one request per form field that is filled in). However, the requests are not working when I replay them. My first thought upon inspecting the requests is that it should contain a valid UUID. But where can I generate this ID, or parse it from the initial request? Is it even possible to manually generate these requests?

Any other suggestion for a load-testing tool for Orbeon would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We often do something similar here, using JMeter, but the idea is the same whatever tool you're using. Indeed, Ajax requests:

- Need to have to be "in" the same session used to generate the page to which they are related, i.e. typically carry the correct `JESSSIONID` cookie.
- Need to refer to the proper UUID. You can find the UUID in the HTML of the page, in the `<input type="hidden" name="$uuid" value="…">`.
- Need to have the correct `<xxf:sequence>1</xxf:sequence>` number. I.e. `1` for the first request made after the page is loaded, then 2, and so on.